# Looping inside ftp command

Tags: linux, image, bash, loops

I'm wondering if I can in some case add 0-10 files, lets say I have a shell script with `video1.jpg`, and want it to go up to `video10.jpg`and start over. The script runs and give `video1.jpg`, I want it to keep adding +1 up to 10.

```
#!/bin/bash
ftp -n -v $HOST << EOT
ascii
user $USER $PASSWD
prompt
get video1.jpg
bye
EOT
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you can try this

```
#!/bin/bash
for((i=1;i<=10;i++))
do
ftp -n -v $HOST << EOT
ascii
user $USER $PASSWD
prompt
get video${i}.jpg
bye
EOT
done
```

Comment: #!/bin/bash
HOST='xxxxxxxx'
USER='xxxxxx'
PASSWD='xxxxxx'

cd /var/www/armando.se/img

ftp -n -v $HOST << EOT
ascii
user $USER $PASSWD
prompt
get video.jpg
bye
EOT

Comment: put set -x below line #!/bin/bash  in script. you will get output on terminal. Please share that log.

Answer (score 0):

I have no chance to try it right now, but this should do:

```
#!/bin/bash
for i in {1..10}; do
ftp -n -v $HOST << EOT
ascii
user $USER $PASSWD
prompt
get video$i.jpg
bye
EOT
done
```

EDIT #2: I was wrong, my answer is almost identical to Shravan Yadav's as you can't loop inside an ftp transaction. You can pick either one as the correct answer, but you should prefer his as he came first I guess :)

Comment: it did make video1.jpg and video 2.jpg but stopped after that

Answer (score 0):

As other answers have already pointed out, the here document you pass to the `ftp` program is just text, and does not have a facility for looping.  However, generating ten ftp sessions to get ten files is wasteful -- you can generate a single here document which instructs `ftp` to fetch them all in one session.

```
#!/bin/bash
(
    printf '%s\n' ascii "user $USER $PASSWD" prompt
    printf 'get video%i.jpg' {1..10}
    printf 'bye\n'
) | ftp -n -v "$HOST"
```

There will be no facility for proper error handling, though.  The real solution is to use a properly scriptable `ftp` program (`lftp`, `ncftp`, what have you) or write your own simple client.

Answer (score 0):

Here is an approach to add ftp inside the loop

```
#!/bin/bash

HOST='hostname'
USER='username'
PASSWD='password'

# Local directory where the files are stored.
cd "/local/directory/from where to upload files/"

# To get all the files added today only.
TODAYSFILES=`find -maxdepth 1 -type f -mtime -1`


# remote server directory to upload backup
REMOTEDIR="/directory on remote ftp computer/"

for FILENAME in ${TODAYSFILES[@]}; do
  ftp -n -v $HOST << EOT
  ascii
  user $USER $PASSWD
  prompt
  cd $REMOTEDIR
  put $FILENAME
  bye
  EOT
done
```